# Jquery runs locally but not on server - typeerror $().rotate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I have been building a site locally and have had all the jquery working fine. I then moved the site live onto a server and suddenly i cannot get any jquery or js to work.

I am calling the library below:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the Jquery code and where i am trying to make the image rotate:

```
<div class="header">
<div>
<img src="images/spin.png" id="spin" height="900px">
</div>
<img src="images/logo.png" class="logo-snoeu" height="135px">
<script>
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
          angle+=2;
         $("#spin").rotate(angle);
    },100);

</script>
```

Here is the link to the page:
www.snoeu.com/

Edit: I am using the following script to initiate the rotate function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the JS file with the `rotate()` plugin in the page and uploaded it to your server?

Comment: It seems i have:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://beneposto.pl/jqueryrotate/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>

Comment: There is your problem then. You need to upload that file to your server with the HTML, and reference it in a `script` element.

Comment: I have added an edit to the question showing where i am calling the plugin from

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xpdd0vz2/

this is where i got it from. I amended this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you include `jquery` 2 times in your site. Just remove he following from your html head section

```
<script src="/mediaplayer/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did the trick! I cannot believe it was something that little. Any idea what caused that to happen? I need to use the mediaplayer script later down the line so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no need to add the same `jquery` library 2 times, it gives a conflict and an error. Just add it once. If you have some other (mediaplayer) script then add it after jquery. Just do not add `jquery` twice.

Comment: Oh ok, since it came with a plugin i thought it was generic to that plugin. Thanks again!